# Open Chrome Developer Tools tabs in a new window to show on multiple monitors

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way where one can open a specific tab of the Chrome Developer Tools in a separate window?  I have got 3 monitors and would like to have the `Sources` tab on one screen and the `Elements` on another screen.  Is this possible?

Comment: Other than opening the site in 2 separate browser windows and enabling the Chrome Developer Tools in each window (one to Sources the other to Elements)? that's all I can think of...

Comment: I'll try it out and see how it goes.  Might be an alternative :)

Comment: @guitarthrower, it is not a solution, when you want to trace how certain lines of javascript code change a page.

Answer (score 2):

I find this limitation frustrating too, all those other monitors are wasted! Here is poor man's solution:

- launch your chrome with `--remote-debugging-port=9999` command line parameter
- right click on your page to debug and select 'Inspect Element' - this is your debug window #1
- open a separate chrome window and navigate to `chrome://inspect`
- click 'Configure...' and add `localhost:9999`
- within a couple of seconds under 'Remote Targets' you should see tabs you can inspect from your other chrome instance
- click on the tab, and now this is your debug window #2

[image: separate windows chrome developer panels]

Unrelated tip: system wide nightmode experience: http://danielsokolowski.blogspot.com/2018/11/windows-10-8-7-night-mode.html